# How can I get my <select> list in AngularJS to show a message ONLY when no value is selected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking at the page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Here they have show a select example but when I open the page in Google Chrome I notice that I **never** see the option -- choose color -- in the browser window.

Can someone explain if this is something to do with the browser. Is it not supposed to appear as it is coded in the page.

```
  <span  class="nullable">
    <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
      <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
    </select>
  </span><br/>
```

I have my own application (AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.8) and I have coded:

```
  <select ng-model="app.config.admin.examTypeId"
          ng-change="home.configChanged()"
          ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in type.dataPlus">
          <option value="">Choose Type</option>
  </select>
```

In my application I **always** see the Choose Type option.

I'm confused as neither seem to work the way I want. What I want is to see the option only the first time if no value has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me its working fine, also there is nothing to do with the browser, since that option value is just a static value ...not even dynamic

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Qcp/1/)**

**html**

```
Color (null allowed):
<span  class="nullable">
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
    <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [{
        name: 'black',
        shade: 'dark'
    }, {
        name: 'white',
        shade: 'light'
    }, {
        name: 'red',
        shade: 'dark'
    }, {
        name: 'blue',
        shade: 'dark'
    }, {
        name: 'yellow',
        shade: 'light'
    }];
});
```

Comment: It may or may not be relevant - you are using angular 1.0.2 in your fiddle while the OP mentions they are using AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.8

Comment: It does'nt matter check this http://jsfiddle.net/S5Qcp/2/ here i'm using AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.8

Comment: Did you check the Angular Documentation page link above. It's not working for me there.

Comment: :) @SamanthaJ for me its working fine.....there is nothing to do with the browser, since that option value is just a static value ...not even dynamic